# Sqoop error while importing to hdfs

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

Im trying to export a small table from mysql to HDFS using sqoop.The table has 2 columns id (primary key ) and name. Im able to list databases and tables via sqoop. But getting exception while importing table to HDFS. Kindly help . Below is the error log.

```
13/12/04 02:05:38 WARN conf.Configuration: session.id is deprecated. 
Instead, use   dfs.metrics.session-id
13/12/04 02:05:38 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: 
Initializing JVM Metrics  withprocessName=JobTracker,sessionId=
13/12/04 02:05:39 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: 
Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/staging/hadoop1439217057
/.staging/job_local1439217057_0001
13/12/04 02:05:39 ERROR 
security.UserGroupInformation:PriviledgedActionException  as:hadoop      
(auth:SIMPLE) 
cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
File does not exist: hdfs://prat1:9000/home/hadoop/usr/sqoop-1.4.3-cdh4.3.0/lib/commons-    compress-1.4.1.jar
13/12/04 02:05:39 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: 
Restoring classloader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35a16869
13/12/04 02:05:39 ERROR tool.ImportTool: 
Encountered IOException running import job:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not  exist:
hdfs://prat1:9000/home/hadoop/usr/
sqoop-1.4.3-cdh4.3.0/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:151)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:111)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:403)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Comment: **13/12/04 02:05:39 ERROR 
security.UserGroupInformation:PriviledgedActionException  as:hadoop      
(auth:SIMPLE)**
Your user does not have the access, please make sure that the user has all the privileges as of HDFS user.

Comment: check this response it may help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799236/4568590](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799236/4568590)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

1. `su root`
2. Type root password
3. `su hdfs`

And then run `sqoop` command and it will work like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

As you are not having write permissions, you are getting security.UserGroupInformation:PriviledgedActionException

Try to login as a hdfs user and then run the sqoop command.

su root

type password

su hdfs

And then run sqoop export command.

Answer (score 0):

Give `/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/<mysqljavaconnector>-bin.jar` file `777` permissions, and also make sure that files in `/usr/lib/sqoop/*` and `/usr/local/hadoop/*` are owned by the same user.